# Is there a shorter way to define a anything element?

Tags: xsd

I want to define a tag in my schema for anything. It should be able to contain any combination of tags and text.
So far I've found

```
<xs:complexType name="customType" mixed="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'm wondering if there is a shorter way. Something like

`<xs:element name="custom" type="anything"/>`

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact you can just write

```
<xsd:element name="XYZ"/>
```

Check here for info: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#anyType

Comment: Okay that's short and easy :)